# Shop-like Webpage That Will Auto-Generate Pages As I Add Items

Tags: javascript, php, web

The story is I have this Shop page that has 4 items in it and they are individually linked to their respective pages then they will all be linked to a cart page to confirm their order.

The problem now is, if say this site is for a client and they have 0 knowledge on coding how can I make it so that I have this page that lets the client put in the info needed and there will be some sort of function to generate pages for that product.

I don't need the whole code for this, I just want someone to tell me the concept of how that's going to work then I can Google the rest myself. Right now, I don't even know what to Google about.

Thx in advance

Comment: You might want to specify what shop you're using (i.e. Woocommerce, Magento, others) or if it's a shop you're made from scratch

Comment: Oh, Its a shop I made from scratch.

Comment: Then you probably want to set up some kind of admin area (password protected), where the client can insert new products which is inserted into your database.
On the shop page, you take the product from the database and show them.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is you have **some sort of database at the background (server)** which can be manipulated by the end-user (Create, Read, Update, Delete) from the **front-end (client)**.

You can use MySQL and PHP to achieve this.

Then you will need the following file:

1. index.php (where the listing of the product appears)
2. product.php (where the details of the product selected appears)

These 2 files will dynamically show the product according to the data of the products stored in the database.

To add new product, you need to create a form:

3. add-product.php (where the ADD NEW PRODUCT form appears)

Using PHP and MYSQL, you can manipulate the database from the front-end.